# convert from bytes32 to bytes with format "\xFF\xFF\xFF"

Tags: solidity, bytes

I'm using [the ECVerify library](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d) and in the test examples in that contract, `function ecverify(bytes32 hash, bytes sig, address signer) returns (bool) {}` expects `bytes sig` in the format `"\xFF\xFF\xFF..."`, and it does not seem to work with a `bytes sig = "0xFFFFFF..."` format.

How do I convert `bytes32 sig = 0xaca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200` to `bytes sig = "\xac\xa7\xda...`?

**Update:** re: Edmund Edgars comment, in [ECVerfiy.sol](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d) there are test examples,

```
function test_v0() returns (bool) {
    bytes32 hash = 0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad;
    bytes memory sig = "\xac\xa7\xda\x99\x7a\xd1\x77\xf0\x40\x24\x0c\xdc\xcf\x69\x05\xb7\x1a\xb1\x6b\x74\x43\x43\x88\xc3\xa7\x2f\x34\xfd\x25\xd6\x43\x93\x46\xb2\xba\xc2\x74\xff\x29\xb4\x8b\x3e\xa6\xe2\xd0\x4c\x13\x36\xea\xce\xaf\xda\x3c\x53\xab\x48\x3f\xc3\xff\x12\xfa\xc3\xeb\xf2\x00";
    return ECVerify.ecverify(hash, sig, 0x0e5cb767cce09a7f3ca594df118aa519be5e2b5a);
}
```

If I replace `bytes sig` with `"0xaca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200"` then it fails. It seems to only work with the `bytes sig = "\xac\xa7\xda..."` format.

I'm using ECVerify for a dApp and will be passing a lot of signatures to it, and it seemed like those need to be in that format, so are there any libraries or something for converting to "\xac\xa7\xda" or how would I send signatures to ECVerify?

Comment: A bytes32 in Solidity is 32 bytes - if you've got a formatting problem it's probably where you're passing the data to the contract. Can you post your failing code?

Comment: posted the code

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
bytes memory sig = "0xaca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200"
```

Solidity interprets this as the literal characters "0", "x", etc. in ASCII.

if you instead use (note the missing `0x`)

```
bytes memory sig =  hex"aca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200"
```

it will interpret it as the bytes in hexadecimal format.

When you are actually passing data to the contract, this won't be an issue, the contract will just accept a sting of bytes, so any formatting needs to be done on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Since your signature is 64 Bytes long you can't store it in a Bytes32 variable. This will NOT work.

```
bytes32 sig = 0xaca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200
```

However you can store the signature in an arbitrary long bytes array as you mentioned:

```
bytes sig = "\xAA\xBB ... \x00"
```

This will be handled as an array in is the same as:

```
bytes1[] memory = new bytes1[](64);
bytes1[0] = 0xAA;
bytes1[1] = 0xBB;
//...
bytes1[63] = 0x00;
```